# Which is the best way to implement click listener in android

Tags: android, textview, android-xml, onclicklistener, android-button

Which is the best way to implement click listener in android ?

1. android:onClick="myClickHandler"
2. implements OnClickListener
3. setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

Comment: I believe many people have different preferences about this. That's why I'm voting to close as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: 1) Is depricated in latest version. 2) Reduce the code readability. 3)More readability and easy to maintain (Useful when creating dynamic layout)

Comment: *1) Is depricated in latest version.* - where did you see this?

Answer (score 2):

- android:onClick="myClickHandler"

This calls the method `myClickHandler(View v)` in the Activity. It's importent to know that the Activity is responsible for this method. Even if you are using this in a layout of a Fragment.

- implements OnClickListener

You have to override the `onClick(View v)`. If you have more Views, which are clickable, you can use this to bundle all code of the views in this method. This is better maintainable. Also it reduces Object creation. If you have multiple buttons, IMO this is better than associate multiple click listeners to the buttons.

```
onClick(View v){
    switch(v.getId())
    case R.id.button1:
       // do something related to this button 1
    case R.id.button2:
       // do something related to this button 2
    ...

}
```

- setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

If you have one view set the listener directly for more readability by using an anonymous class. With this you mostly have the implementation of the listener in the scope of the view.

There is no real convention when to use the second or third approach. It's mostly opinion based as Simon André Forsberg already commented. But be careful with the first approach, especially in Fragment scenarios.